# MySQL CPP connector compilation issue

Tags: c++, linux, mysql-connector

I am getting following error 
 Versions < 4.1.13 (for MySQL 4.1.x) and < 5.0.7 for (MySQL 5.0.x) are not

But I have version mysql55-devel.x86_64 installed on the system. 
What could be the issue ?

Complete cmake message:

```
-- Environment compile flags:   
-- Environment link flags: 
-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/ec2-user/build/2_0/build_server/lib/linux/gcc/64/include
-- ENV{MYSQL_DIR} = 
-- MySQL Include dir: /home/ec2-user/build/2_0/build_server/lib/linux/gcc/64/include
-- MySQL Library    : /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so
-- MySQL Library dir: /usr/lib64/mysql
-- MySQL CXXFLAGS: 
-- MySQL Link flags: 
-- Looking for mysql_set_character_set
-- Looking for mysql_set_character_set - not found
CMake Error at FindMySQL.cm:182 (MESSAGE):
  Versions < 4.1.13 (for MySQL 4.1.x) and < 5.0.7 for (MySQL 5.0.x) are not
  supported.  Please update your libraries.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:173 (INCLUDE)
```

I think error is mysql_set_character_set not found and it is showing wrong error message.

Comment: what is the version of your `mysql` server?? (BTW, you cut the error messages, and you should improve your question).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch for compilation do I required mysql server ?

Comment: Show your compilation command. Use the `-Wall` and `-H` options to `g++`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It is failing at configuration steps while running cmake. At that time I don't think compilation option make any difference.

Comment: I don't know what was the bug installing mysql server fixed the bug. 
sudo yum install mysql55-server.x86_64